# Strange error when loading MP3 on OSX

Tags: java, audio, jlayer

I'm using tritonus, mp3spi, and jl1.0.1 . When I try and debug OR run in Eclipse (OSX) it throws a `NullPointerException`. But on Windows it works just fine. Any advice? I'd love to get this working to develop cross-platform.

The part that makes it strange is it's only on Mac.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at com.plake.audio.JukeBox.load(JukeBox.java:26) 
    at com.plake.gamestate.MenuState.<init>(MenuState.java:59) 
    at com.plake.gamestate.GameStateManager.loadState(GameStateManager.java:85) 
    at com.plake.gamestate.GameStateManager.<init>(GameStateManager.java:49) 
    at com.plake.main.GamePanel.init(GamePanel.java:54) 
    at com.plake.main.GamePanel.run(GamePanel.java:59) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

JukeBox:

```
  public static void load(final String s, final String n) {
    try {
        if (JukeBox.clips.get(n) != null) {
            return;
        }
        final AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(JukeBox.class.getResourceAsStream(s));
        final AudioFormat baseFormat = ais.getFormat();
        final AudioFormat decodeFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, baseFormat.getSampleRate(), 16, baseFormat.getChannels(), baseFormat.getChannels() * 2, baseFormat.getSampleRate(), false);
        final AudioInputStream dais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodeFormat, ais);
        final Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(dais);
        JukeBox.clips.put(n, clip);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Error is after the if statement

Comment: Can we have some code to analyze?

Comment: The JukeBox class, particularly the load method and a highlight on line 26 would be preferable.

Comment: Stupid of me, sorry @stuntmania